# How do I completely uninstall default Unity Greeter and use text mode login instead?

Tags: login, lightdm, login-screen, unity-greeter

If I would like to completely uninstall the default Unity Greeter and use text mode login instead, how should I go about it?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS - the regular flavor; with Unity.

I prefer a command-line solution that can be scripted later.

Comment: So you want to login with a command line and then start the GUI? or just Command line?

Comment: Yes, that's what I would like: log in with a command line to a command-line environment, I can always figure how to autostart X later (and on a per-user basis). Continuing to autostart the GUI is also fine, though: switching to **[text mode login](http://cdn5.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/screenshot_01.png)** is the important part.

Comment: if you uninstall unity there will be no way to start gui. However...

Comment: @Tim I was trying to uninstall **Unity Greeter**, not Unity. However, I tried the proposed solution (modifying /etc/default/grub with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"`) in a question this is supposedly a duplicate of, and it doesn't work for me. Have any of you marking this as duplicate actually try it?

Comment: I doubt any of us have tried it. We closed it because you seemed to be asking the same thing. In what way does it not work?